# Populate chart using associative array

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to populate a jqplot chart using an array ( dateVal ) that contains the following data :

```
console.log( index + " : " + dateVal[index]);

OUTPUT BELOW

February 01, 2013 : 12
February 02, 2013 : 12
February 03, 2013 : 12
February 04, 2013 : 43
February 05, 2013 : 45
```

I am trying to use this code but it throws an uncaught error :

```
var plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [dateVal], {

    title:'Rubric Average Scores',
    gridPadding:{right:35},
    axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'},
        //tickOptions:{formatString:'%b-%y'},
        tickInterval:'1 month',
        angle: -30,
    }},
    yaxis:{label:'Average Score',},
    series:[{lineWidth:3, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
});
```

Comment: Mind your trailing commas; they might throw off IE

Answer (score 0):

I had to make dateVal an array of arrays...